# Fill every field on page with a string using a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, html, field, bookmarklet

I'm testing for text input fields that have issues with various characters, and I have no idea where to start, but I want a bookmarklet that fills every form on the page with

```
 ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿƒΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφχψωϑϒϖ•…′″‾⁄℘ℑℜ™ℵ←↑→↓↔↵⇐⇑⇒⇓⇔∀∂∃∅∇∈∉∋∏∑−∗√∝∞∠∧∨∩∪∫∴∼≅≈≠≡≤≥⊂⊃⊄⊆⊇⊕⊗⊥⋅⌈⌉⌊⌋〈〉◊♠♣♥♦"&<>ŒœŠšŸˆ˜‌‍‎‏–—‘’‚“”„†‡‰‹›€
```

can anyone help?

Comment: with zepto: `$("input[type=text]").val( strHere )`

Comment: @dandavis Had to tweak it a bit, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarklet using `querySelectorAll` for modern browsers (replace 'my_test_string' with the (optionally escaped) teststring you require):

```
javascript:(function(s){for(var n=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'), L=n.length; L--; n[L].value=s);})('my_test_string');
```

Note that you can pass in multiple CSS selectors:

```
javascript:(function(s){for(var n=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text], input[type=hidden], textarea'), L=n.length; L--; n[L].value=s);})('my_test_string');
```

Alternative fallback for legacy browsers (using `getElementsByTagName` in conjunction with a short-circuit type test for 'text'):

```
javascript:(function(s){for(var n=document.getElementsByTagName('input'), L=n.length; L--; n[L].type.toLowerCase()==='text' && (n[L].value=s));})('my_test_string');
```

Pure javascript, no libraries required!

Hope this gets you started!

<sup>PS: Yes, it's 'golfed': it's a bookmarklet (and we need to leave as much room as possible for the (optionally escaped) test-string).. besides the routine is as basic as it can get.. note that the semicolon closing the packed for-loop is *required*!</sup>